# Haag’s theorem in finite volume

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, volume

I’ve been reading on Haag’s theorem and found this proof that uses standard QFT instead of the axiomatic kind: https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.08875

It essentially boils down to saying that the vacuum should be invariant under spatial translations $T|\Omega> = 0$ where $T$ is defined such that $T\phi(t,x) = \phi(t,x + a)$. In the interaction picture, $U(t)^{\dagger}TU(t) = T_{interaction}$

By using some algebraic manipulations, one can show that $|\Omega> = |0>$.

Now I have heard that Haag’s theorem does not apply when working in a finite spatial volume. This can be proved in the algebraic framework of QFT, but I’m wondering how it can be proved with the use of the translation operator. I’m thinking that in a spatial volume, the vacuum is no longer invariant under spatial translation, since there can be particles “outside” the particular volume that we are in, and thus the argument no longer applies. Is this correct?

Comment: I think they typically use periodic boundary conditions (flat torus) for convenience. You can therefore define a translation operator.